# I made my own std::vector but I am generating an error

Tags: c++

Is there something wrong with the way that I allocated memory for `T* data` and also with my destructor? Mind you that `T* data` was already given to me as a private variable. I keep getting a segmentation fault error in my terminal. Also, I get the following warning:

```
unused variable 'data_' [-Wunused-variable] T* data_ = new T[size_];
```

Here is my code:

```
public:
    // Define the iterator type to just be a pointer to T.
    typedef T* iterator;

    // Constructs an empty vector. Allocate an initial capacity of 1 element,
    // but do not add an element to the vector (i.e. capacity will be 1 while
    // size will be 0). You do not need to worry about bad_alloc exceptions.
    csc340_vector() {
        size_ = 0;
        capacity_ = 1;
        T* data_ = new T[size_];
    }

    // Destructs/de-allocates dynamic memory (if any was allocated).
    ~csc340_vector(){
       delete [] data_;
    }
private:
    T* data_;                // Storage for the elements
    unsigned int size_;      // Number of elements defined in the vector
    unsigned int capacity_;  // Number of elements that the vector can hold

};
```

Also, I have tried to use `T* data_ = new T[capacity_];` but it still generates the same unused variable warning.

Comment: read up on RAII. Your poorly formatted, nearly unreadable code screams for that understanding. _data is a local variable.  Why the need for an underscore?

Comment: Did you intend to allocate 0 bytes? Perhaps you want to allocate for your capacity instead? It would be helpful to see a short complete example of the problem since how you use it is important as well. Unless you've roced all warnings to errors then unused variable is not an error, but the fact that you're getting it leads me to believe the problem exists in the code you have not shown. You might read up on the rule of three as well.

Comment: compile with `-Wshadow`

Comment: Im mainly wondering if I have constructed the empty vector correctly because it seems like I am creating a whole new one and that variable is not being used.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe data_ was given to me

Comment: @garcy Please at least post the whole class code. It is hard to help you with the information given...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        T* data_ = new T[size_];
```

is not your member data_. It is a locally declared variable.

To use the member you write

```
data_ = new T[size_];
```

or if there are ambiguities

```
this->data_ = new T[size_];
```

Comment: I understand, so how do I use the private variable T* data_ to make an empty vector instead? I'm sure thats where my error is generated due to me creating a whole new local variable unrelated to the one given to me

Comment: I've tried writing it both ways before an generated error : incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: That means this error is fixed. Now you need to read up on RAII.

Comment: @FeonaGarcia My pleasure. If my answer resolved your question you should click the green checkmark.

Comment: It would probably be worth mentioning benefit of initialising `data_` in the constructor's initialiser list, rather than in the body of the constructor.   Also, from the comments in the OP's code, it appears the intent is to initialise `data_`  as `new T[_capacity]`, not `new T[_size]`.

Comment: @garcy ***object was probably modified after being freed.*** Google for the rule of 3 / 5 / 0.